# Validating number of digits in a number oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, decimal

I want to validate the number of digits of numbers so I can check if they follow the rules provided (9,6);

- no more than 9 digits in total
- max 3 digits before the dot
- max 6 digits after the dot

For example Column A have the following values;

- 123.456434 --> correct
- 12.4535 --> correct
- 13234.3543 --> not correct (to many digits before the dot)
- 13.4757832 --> not correct (to many digits after the dot)

In a previous test I only tested the digits after the dot with the following sql;

select column_a
,case when length(regexp_substr(column_a,'\d+$')) > (9,6) then 'Not OK'
else 'OK'
end column_a_test
from table

However this doesn't seem to work to check the digits before the dot. How can I tweak the sql so that it tests both digits before and after the dot?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
select . . . ,
       (case when regexp_like(column_a, '^[0-9]{0-3},[0-9]{0-6}$')
             then 'OK' else 'NOT OK'
        end)
```

This assumes that the comma is required.  If not, use `'^[0-9]{0-3}[,]?[0-9]{0-6}$'`.

Comment: I now see I that I used comma where the numbers are in column have dots instead of comma's. I edit my question and replaced the comma's, so where do I use the [,] ?

Comment: next to that. A dot is not required in the number so a value of 100 would be correct as well

Comment: @Jordi_h821 . . . My advice was missing a character.  It should be `[,]?`.

Answer (score 2):

Your adapted question with optional decimal point requires some care in the length check.

You can't set it simple optional in the regexp `[.]?` as this would accept long integers e.g. `1000`

Simple use two options in the regexp, one without the decimal point `^[[:digit:]]{0,3}$`

and the other with it `^[[:digit:]]{0,3}[.][[:digit:]]{0,6}$`

The sample query

```
select num,
case when regexp_like(num, '(^[[:digit:]]{0,3}$|^[[:digit:]]{0,3}[.][[:digit:]]{0,6}$)' )
          then 'OK' else 'NOT OK'
 end as is_ok
from tab;

NUM        IS_OK 
---------- ------
123.45643  OK    
12.4535    OK    
13234.3543 NOT OK
13.4757832 NOT OK
13,475     NOT OK
38383      NOT OK
100        OK
```

Note also that the [correct syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix002.htm#i690823) for occurence operator is `{m,n}`  and not `{m-n}`